# How to retrieve PDF in iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, pdf, nsdocumentdirectory

I am trying to retrieve PDF file using NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains.i am getting path for PDF file but how to convert that pdf file into nsdata or nsmutabledata(bytes).Here is my code to get path of PDF.

```
NSArray *arrayPaths1 =
NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask,YES);
NSString *path1 = [arrayPaths1 objectAtIndex:0];
path1 = [path1 stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"mypdffile.pdf"];
```

in path1 i am getting the path and to get byte data I am trying

```
[decodedData writeToFile:path1 atomically:YES];
```

decodedData is NSMutableData.decodedData is nil.Please help me.How can I solve this problem?

Comment: why you are wring file which is already i guess into document folder?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:<#path of your file#>]` for that purpose.

In your case it should be:

```
decodedData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile: path1];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code..

```
 NSData *dataPdf = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:pdfOnline.url];

    //Get path directory
    NSArray *arrayPaths1 =
    NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask,YES);
    //Create PDF_Documents directory
    NSString * documentsDirectory = [arrayPaths1 objectAtIndex:0];
    documentsDirectory = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"mypdffile.pdf"];

    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] documentsDirectory withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:nil];

    NSString *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", documentsDirectory, @"PDFRefYouPreferred"];

    [dataPdf writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
```

Hope it will fix the issue..!